# OpenLDAP Unsalt SSHA userPassword in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, openldap

I'm trying to unsalt the userPassword which is SSHA encrypted in our openldap environment. I don't want the plain text password but want to get to the unsalted hashed password.

Any thoughts? Even the method for hashing and salting would prove useful.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php#104232 ?

Comment: Or `function checkSSHAPass ($plainTextPass, $ldapPass) { if (strtoupper(substr($ldapPass, 0, 6)) != '{SSHA}') return FALSE; $passStr = base64_decode(substr($ldapPass, 6)); return substr($passStr, 0, 20) == sha1($plainTextPass.substr($passStr, 20), TRUE); }` ?

Comment: @DaveRandom that was exactly it! Out of curiosity did you find that or code it yourself? I searched for a while and didn't come across anything. Thanks :)

Comment: Just looked at [this page](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html) and wrote it based on that info. It's not that hard, you basically just have to reverse the creation process to get the salt (which is the part you actually need to know), then use the salt to make a hash from the user supplied value and compare it with the original hash. The one bit that might catch you out is the fact that it is stored in binary and not ASCII-hex format, which is why the `TRUE` argument is passed to `sha1()`. You would need to `pack()` on PHP<5.

Comment: The first line is just a sanity check to make sure the string you supplied as the password from LDAP has some chance of being valid. You could remove it if only you will ever use the function and you have complete control over the data source.

Comment: Got it and that page is perfect. The first line makes sense, especially since I'm doing some funky stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You want to somehow convert

```
salt + sha1(salt + password)
```

into

```
sha1(password)
```

I don't see how this would be possible without knowing the plaintext password. If it was possible, salting itself would be a useless and trivially reversible technique.

Comment: It's definitely salt + sha1(salt + pass)? I've seen sha1(pass + salt) + salt as well. I'm going to try it this way as well.

I'm taking an input and comparing the hashes of the input vs stored userPassword. This is a bit deeper than authentication otherwise I would just test bind.

Comment: I was describing the abstract process, it seems the actual algorithm in OpenLDAP is `'{SSHA}' + base64(sha1(password + salt)) + salt`.